# How can I determine whether it is a minimum or maximum of a functional?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

For such a problem:

> Find  the  curve $y(x)$  which  satisfies $\displaystyle y(0)=0$ and $\displaystyle y(\pi / 2)=0$,  and which extremizes the functional
>   $$
> J[y]=\int_{0}^{\pi / 2} \left[y^{2}-y'^{2}-2 y \cosh (x)\right]dx.
> $$

My attempt:

Let $F(x,y,y^{\prime})=y^{2}-y^{\prime 2}-2 y \cosh (x)$, then we have $F_{y}=2y-2\cosh(x)$ and $F_{y^{\prime}}=-2y^{\prime}$, yielding Euler's equation as
$$
F_{y}-\frac{d}{d x} F_{y^{\prime}}=2y-2\cosh(x)-\frac{d}{d x} (-2y^{\prime})=0
$$
$$
\Longrightarrow y''(x)+y(x)-\cosh(x)=0.
$$
With the boundary conditions $\displaystyle y(0)=0$ and $\displaystyle y(\pi/2)=0$, we can solve the ordinary differential equation and obtain
$$
y(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left[-\cos (x)+\cosh (x)-\cosh \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \sin (x)\right].
$$
Besides, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial^{2} F}{\partial y^{2}}&=2\\
\frac{\partial^{2} F}{\partial y \partial y^{\prime}}&=0\\
\frac{\partial^{2} F}{\partial y^{\prime 2}}&=-2
\end{aligned}
$$
So we can calculate the second variation that
$$
h^{2} \frac{\partial^{2} F}{\partial y^{2}}+2h h^{\prime} \frac{\partial^{2} F}{\partial y \partial y^{\prime}}+h^{\prime 2} \frac{\partial^{2} F}{\partial y^{\prime 2}}=2h^{2}-2h^{\prime 2}
$$
where $h$ represents the increment.

Question:

1. I don't know how to use the second variation (as above) to determine whether there is a minimum or maximum of a functional.
2. I don't know if the function deduced by the E-L equation is an extremal for sure. Because for a function of a single variable in calculus, $f'(x_{0})=0$ is a necessary condition for $x_{0}$ to be a local minimum/maximum point of $f(x)$, namely it does not mean $f(x_{0})$ must be an extremum.

Comment: Euler-Lagrange is the equivalent of $f'(x_0)=0$ There is no $y(x_0)$, the $y$ you found *is* the $x_0$ in the analogy. Given the form of the integrand, it is entirely likely that the $y$ you found may be neither a min or a max, and instead might be a saddle point (where point means a function in a function space).

Comment: @NinadMunshi Sorry about the typo. Do you know how to use the second variation to determine whether it is an extremum of the functional or not?

Comment: Yes, just derive EL the usual way again with $y\mapsto y+\epsilon h$ but instead of taking $\frac{dJ}{d\epsilon}$, now take $\frac{d^2J}{d\epsilon^2}$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks, I may get your point. I'd appreciate it so much if you would use my example to show the steps in detail (if possible, but thank you anyway)

Comment: I can't atm since I am on mobile currently but I'll answer your question later if no one has already.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks! It seems necessary for me to wait for an answer since I failed...

Comment: @NinadMunshi Hi, how is it going with it? I have been trying what you said but never succeed to get an answer. This problem is really special.

Answer (score 2):

Take

$$J[y+\epsilon h] = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (y+\epsilon h)^2 - (y' + \epsilon h')^2 - 2(y+\epsilon h)\cosh x dx$$

Then calculate

$$\frac{d^2J}{d\epsilon^2} = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} 2h^2 - 2h'^2 dx$$

Notice that unlike the first derivative case, the value of this integral is entirely dependent on the arbitrary variation to the path $h$.

Depending on the choice of $h$, the second derivative may either be positive, negative, or zero. In an analogy to $2$D limits, linearly independent $h$s correspond to different "directions" in which to approach a point (except in an infinite dimensional function space this time).

Thus the stationary path found is actually a saddle point, i.e. we can find other paths with larger or smaller values than the stationary path when plugged in to the functional.

Comment: The integration of $(2h^{2}-2h^{\prime 2})$ is likely to be negative always when the two end points give 0, from lots of my tests. Could you give an example for $(2h^{2}-2h^{\prime 2})>0$?

Comment: @Thinkpad Hmm, I'll let you know if I find one. I find it hard to believe that such a function would not exist, especially since integration by parts didn't show anything special $(\int 2h(h+h'')dx)$